# Java JPA loaded OneToMany list not updated after change

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Maybe it is a really stupid question but I just can't find solution. I have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Comment> comments;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
```

When I launch application, I retrieve all comments by getter (it is loaded properly). When I however delete/add another comment, database is updated but application is not until rerun. When creating comment it is persisted - it is in DB - so I do not understand how is it not updated. Tried various cascade types but I do not think it is necessary here anyway. I also tried EAGER and it does not work as well.

When I manually get comments from DB after adding/deleting it works but that is I think very dirty solution right?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why would it be updated? When you execute a query, you get what the database contains *at that time*; You don't get a live view of what the query returns later. Don't load everything at startup. Execute the query to load the comments every time you need the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch that entity  you pasted a piece of code of once again. Already fetched list will not magicly update itself.

Its like using SQL - you have rerun the query to see the updates. ORM just maps SQL results row into objects.

Comment: Oh so I have to manually pop/add that element in list so it is updated or I have to manually call query? Is not there a way how to tell the application to track the changes and propagate?

Comment: You would have to broadcast add/remove event internally to notify required components that something something changed, but that is done aside database. But still - reaction to such event would be to fetch data and eventually update list. Its what you call "manuall" way anyway.

Comment: Okay thanks. It is weird though because it seems to me only natural that if I am persisting something to database, to keep data integrity, entity manager or something should update the internal fields as well.

Comment: It could be nice, but think in global scale - if you would have billion comments, you rly would like to keep that in list? you would run out of resources in no time. And in fact as you would keep all the data in app - database would be useless.

Comment: Well because it is mapped by id I work with comments specific to project. So technically I have that in my memory when that specific project is loaded. If I manually query I would waste much more than if entity manager would selectively update internal field. So I still do not see why the update can't be automatic. To me it seems it inserts point of failure for user to break data integrity. That said I add comment when created to list and session.update(project) and everything is fine - as you pointed out before in your answer.

Comment: Actually it is you that introduces data inconsistency vulnerability by duplicating it in unmanaged way. Let database hold your data.

Comment: Now I dont understand. How can I manage it automatically? I would still have to manually fetch data from database after change (as you pointed out it will not magically updates itself) and then I would waste a lot of resources. As you pointed out the database can be huge and even if the table is indexed it can take lower the performance. If the database would be accessed from multiple points, then maybe updating from it would be reasonable, otherwise it seems to me very inefficent?